# How do I get a ComboBox to show the DisplayMember after loading?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a C# windows form app and in the form load method, I load up some comboboxes. For one of them, the MeasureType, it is displaying the field that is the ValueMember, which is just a meaningless ID. I want the MeasureType description (MeasureType1). I noticed that if I refresh or I call the function to load the comboboxes twice (back to back), it then works and shows the description field. I have tried setting the DataSource both first and last in the order of assigning the properties in the code below. All the other comboboxes are working as expected. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
    private void MeasureForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadForm();
        LoadForm();  //if I call twice, it shows DisplayMember field
    }

    private void LoadForm()
    {
        measLoader = new MeasureData();

        cbCurrentMeasures.DataSource = measLoader.GetMeasuresWithEmpty();
        cbCurrentMeasures.DisplayMember = "MeasureName";
        cbCurrentMeasures.ValueMember = "MeasureID";           

        //*** THIS ONE IS NOT SHOWING DISPLAYMEMBER ***  
        cbTypes.DataSource = measLoader.GetMeasureTypes();
        cbTypes.DisplayMember = "MeasureType1";
        cbTypes.ValueMember = "MeasureTypeID";


        cbMethods.DataSource = measLoader.GetWebServiceMethodsWithEmpty();
        cbMethods.DisplayMember = "MethodName";
        cbMethods.ValueMember = "WebServiceMethodID";

        cbProperties.DataSource = measLoader.GetClassPropertiesWithEmpty();
        cbProperties.DisplayMember = "DisplayField";
        cbProperties.ValueMember = "PropertyID";

        chklistItems.DataSource = measLoader.GetItems();
        ((ListBox)chklistItems).DisplayMember = "ItemName";
        ((ListBox)chklistItems).ValueMember = "ItemID";    
    }

    private void cbTypes_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cbTypes.Text.Contains("QI"))
        {
            cbProperties.Enabled = false;
            cbProperties.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            cbProperties.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

MeasureData class that uses linq-to-sql:

```
 public List<MeasureType> GetMeasureTypes()
 {
     return db.MeasureTypes.ToList<MeasureType>();
 }
```

Comment: The field in the database is called MeasureType, which is same as the table name, so linq-to-sql changed it to MeasureType1 in the dbml file. But it says its sourcing from MeasureType.  This is something to look into though. None of my other comboboxes have this column name issue.

Comment: Ok found another clue- the SelectedIndexChanged event handler is part culprit. I commented the code in there out, removed the second call to LoadForm, and it's working. The code that sets Enabled and SelectedIndex on cbProperties is somehow affecting things. There are no event handlers on cbProperties.

Comment: I moved the loading of cbProperties ahead of cbTypes and now it's working. I guess it was tripping up by trying to set the SelectedIndex on a ComboBox that wasn't loaded with data yet. Funny how I solve things as soon as I post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved the loading of cbProperties ahead of cbMeasureTypes since the eventhandler on cbMeasureTypes was trying to set the SelectedIndex of cbProperties before it had any data.